# binding to input blob imperatively

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

**How do we imperatively bind to an input blob?**

I'd like to be able to read blobs inside of my azure function. One way to do this is to add a parameter like this one:

```
[Blob("%MyInputBlob%/{FileName}", FileAccess.Read)]  Stream input
```

However, this won't work for me because I will need to read multiple blobs, and they have different `{filenames}`.

I understand there's an imperative binding solution to write to an output like so:

```
        var attributes = new Attribute[]
        {
                new BlobAttribute(path),
                new StorageAccountAttribute(connection)
        };
        using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes))
        {
            writer.Write(payload);
        }
```

**Is there a similar binding capability for INPUT blobs?**

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic input binding, you could just change the binding type as follows:

```
var blobString = await binder.BindAsync<string>(attributes);
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625498/azure-functions-blob-stream-dynamic-input-bindings) you could refer to.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly - you can get a reference to the blob container without specifying a filename:

```
[Blob("ContainerName", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer container
```

Then from here - read the file:

```
container.GetBlockBlobReference("filename");
```

Comment: thats cool! is that the main reason to use `CloudBlobContainer ` ?

Comment: Not sure it's the main reason but it's a way you can get to the container without specifying a blob name